# Predicting a Markov chain next state using previously predicted states

Tags: prediction, simulation, markov-process

Suppose we have a Markov chain with two states `A` and `B`.
This associated transition matrix is:

\begin{equation}
P_{mc}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0.7\\
0.6 & 0.4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

This matrix is empirical and computed from a set of observations:

e.g :`A->B->A->A->A->B->A->A->B->B->A->B->B->A->B->A->B->A->B->B->B`

My question is, After predicting a new state (`B` or `A`) how accurate is it to generate a new transition matrix `P_mc` based on the new sequence and is there any theoretical limits to doing this?

Comment: I don't quite understand what the new matrix' generation is based on - are you updating the matrix based on a new observation, or the actual *prediction*?

Comment: The matrix is updated using the actual prediction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using your current predictions to influence the estimation of your future predictions, you get a positive feedback loop and wave goodbye to any real-world distribution.

For example, an initial transition matrix $[[0.99, 0.01], [0.01, 0.99]]$ will asymptotically wind up predicting either only As or only Bs, depending on your start state.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you mean by 'you get a positive feedback loop and wave goodbye to any real-world distribution'. Are you talking about a statistical distribution or parallel computing

Comment: Statistical. Your transition matrix will asymptotically collapse to predicting either A->A or A->B with 100% probability regardless of the real-world probability.

Comment: Can you tell me on what basis you concluded this?

Comment: Just think through this. Let's take a string ABBBAAAA as our starting point. Empirically, your matrix is entries for A are [.67, .33], let's roll with that. Your predictor peeks at the last A, rolls the dice, and predicts another A 2/3 of the time. Your new matrix is [.80,.20]. You now look at your new A, roll for another A 80% of the time, updating the matrix to [.83, .17], and again for [.86, .14]... Getting an A reinforces the odds of producing an A and vice versa. I didn't normalize the whole matrix for compactness' sake, but the pattern holds.